# Adding background shape to an image using pseudo selectors

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code

```css
.about-img-top {
  padding-top: 39px;
  padding-left: 95px;
}

.about-img {
  padding-top: 39px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.Rectangle-2-Copy {
  width: 526px;
  height: 248px;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  z-index: -1;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 64px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-7">
  <img src="https://cdn.zeplin.io/588714a1f51baed2b98908bc/assets/C2477822-CF77-4CC3-966D-37305572AC79.png" class="about-img-top img-responsive " alt="payment_gateway_company">
  <div class="Rectangle-2-Copy">
  </div>
</div>
```

This works fine, and I had to add an empty div with css properties in it.

But can I do it without using an empty div? By adding couple of CSS to the image it self?

This is what I tried

https://jsfiddle.net/74s293wt/

I am new to HTML/CSS, and I have tried couple of googling but didn't help.

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/74s293wt/2/

Comment: @Santi No. The output my fiddle generated is correct. But i want to achieve it using css and not by an empty div

Comment: Correct... look at the HTML in my fiddle. The empty div is not there and the output is identical to yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could insert the content using `:before` or `:after` if you'd rather not have the empty `div`. Try this:

```css
.about-img-top {
  padding-top: 39px;
  padding-left: 95px;
}

.col-md-7:before {
  content: '';
  width: 526px;
  height: 248px;
  background-color: #c00;
  z-index: -1;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 64px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-7">
  <img src="https://cdn.zeplin.io/588714a1f51baed2b98908bc/assets/C2477822-CF77-4CC3-966D-37305572AC79.png" class="about-img-top img-responsive " alt="payment_gateway_company">
</div>
```